# WordPress REST API get all terms from all levels for custom hierarchical taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I've created a custom hierarchical taxonomy in WordPress that has two levels.  Is it possible to use the REST API to return all terms from all levels in a single call?

I thought using [domain]/wp-json/wp/v2/vl_bok_primary_cat would return all terms like it does for non-hierarchical taxonomies, but it's only returning second-level terms.

If that's the expected behavior, I know I can use these two calls as a workaround to get all terms from both levels:

[domain]/wp-json/wp/v2/vl_bok_primary_cat?parent=0

[domain]/wp-json/wp/v2/vl_bok_primary_cat

But it seems odd that there wouldn't be a single call to accomplish the same thing, unless I'm missing something.